# jquery ajax script for page transition not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

js and jquery rookie here. I'm trying to create a page transition effect on a wordpress site using code that i found on a tutorial. The first part seems to work fine but the transition stops halfway and it doesn't load the page I clicked. After that the site freezes, I try to click the navigation links but nothing happens.

Here's the code I'm using. The #content id is the part that i'm trying to change of course and the 'slide-out' class has the animation that i would like to use.

Any help would be apprechiated :)
Thanks.

```
$("#site-navigation a").on("click", function (event) {

event.preventDefault()

      var href = $(this).attr("href")

      window.history.pushState(null, null, href)

      //$("#site-navigation li").removeClass("current-menu-item")
      //$(this).addClass("current-menu-item")

      $.ajax({
        url: href,
        success: function (data) {

          $("#content").addClass('slide-out', function () {

            var newPage = $(data).filter("#content").html()

            $("#content").html(newPage)

            $("#content").removeClass('slide-out')
          })
        }
        })    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function({ <your code> })
```